# Loops of the projective plane embedded in the projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space

Let $\mathbb{R}P^2$ denote the real projective plane and suppose that $a$ is a non-contractible loop in $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Since $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $a^2$ is contractible. I am trying to figure out the following:

Let $i:\mathbb{R}P^2\to\mathbb{R}P^3$ be the inclusion map (e.g. we obtain $\mathbb{R}P^3$ by identifying antipodal points of $\mathbb{S}^3$, so we can obtain $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as quotient of the subspace of $\mathbb{S}^3$ where the $4th$ coordinate is constantly 0). If we now see $a$  as a loop in $\mathbb{R}P^3$, does it become contractible? or does it remain non-contractible? In other words, is $i_*[a]=0$, where $i_*$ is the induced group homomorphisms between the fundamental groups?

I have little understanding of the real projective space, I don't even know how to compute its fundamental group (although I'm trying for a Seifert-van Kampen application) and it is hard for me to conceptualize the loop $a$ in $\mathbb{R}P^3$. Any intuitive or explicit hints and answers to help me understand this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a curve on $S^n$ with $\gamma(1)=-\gamma(0)$ then as a closed loop on $S^n/\pm 1$ it is not contractible because $\gamma_t(1)=- \gamma_t(0)$ has to be preserved in an homotopy

Comment: @reuns Could you please elaborate on why this preservation does not allow contractability?

Comment: The "lift" idea is just saying that the length of $\gamma_t$ on $S^n/\pm1$ is the same as the length on $S^n$, which is at least $\pi$

Comment: Have you learned anything about covering space theory? Because if you have not, then my answer to your question would be "go learn covering space theory". With that, it is possible to write a more informative answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher just the basic theory

Comment: Well, if you've ever seen the proof that $\pi_1(S^1)\approx\mathbb Z$ using the covering map $\mathbb R \mapsto S^1$, then you might understand the proof that $\pi_1(\mathbb RP^2) \approx \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, and how to see your path $a$ as the generator, using the covering map $S^2 \mapsto \mathbb RP^2$.

Comment: And, actually, the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913873/26501) says pretty much everything that I would say along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not contractible to see this consider the fibration $p_n:S^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$,

A contractible loop $c:\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$, lifts to a contractible loop of $S^n$ since for a Serre fibration homotopies can be lifted.

The non contractible loop of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ can be constructed by taking a path $c$ in the upper hemisphere of $S^n$ wich meets the equator in two points which are identified by $p_n$, the embedding $\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$ result from an embedding $i_n:S^n\rightarrow S^{n+1}$ and $i_n(c)$ is a non closed segment such that $p_n(i_{n+1}(c))$ is a loop, so it is not contractible since its lift is not a loop.